# We could not confirm that you authenticated to your Dev Hub org using JWT-based auth flow with the 'DreamHouse_demo' Connected App

Tags: git, jwt, cicd

**Build an Automated CI/CD Pipeline with GitLab**

> We could not confirm that you authenticated to your Dev Hub org using
>   JWT-based auth flow with the 'DreamHouse_demo' Connected App.

I am doing the Build an **Automated CI/CD Pipeline with GitLab** Trailhead.

I have followed the steps in Integrate with GitLab diligently I feel and when I authorize my playground for JWT, I get the success message but when I try validate the challenge I get the below error

Step not yet complete in My Trailhead Playground 3

> We could not confirm that you authenticated to your Dev Hub org using
>   JWT-based auth flow with the 'DreamHouse_demo' Connected App.

I am baffled what i am doing wrong as this is a step by step guide basically i am following and successful it seems.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when I tried to validate the **[Integrate with Gitlab](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/automate-cicd-with-gitlab/integrate-with-gitlab)** unit. But no problem, Go ahead and complete the next unit ([Package your App and Automate CI/CD](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/automate-cicd-with-gitlab/package-your-app-and-automate-cicd)). after adding the **.gitlab-ci.yml** file and filling it, replace this line:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -md md5 -in assets/server.key.enc -out assets/server.key -k $SERVER_KEY_PASSWORD
```

With

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -md sha256 -in assets/server.key.enc -out assets/server.key -k $SERVER_KEY_PASSWORD
```

in fact, we should use sha256 instead of md5 otherwise there will be an error when decrypting. After that, do a commit and check if the authentication works successfully on the Gitlab Pipeline. if yes you must be able to validate the challenge.

Hope that's helpful